# Convert foreach to for in PHP

Tags: php

```
foreach ( $this->parent->get_sections(null, $this->parent->author) as $section)
{
  //...
}
```

I'm trying to do is force the loop to output each `$section` in the order I want. Each `$section`'s name can be retrieved by `$section->name`. Let's say that I want to output `$section` "Section 2" first and then "Section 1" (and not in the order of the `foreach`). How can I force it do that? I presume the proper way would be a `for` loop with an if checking section names each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing the structure of your code, I would do something like.

```
// Get Org Sections
$sections = $this->parent->get_sections(null, $this->parent->author);

// Loop thru sections to get an array of names
foreach ( $sections as $key=>$section)
{ 
$sorted_sections[$section->name] = $key;
}

// Sort Array
//ksort — Sort an array by key
//krsort — Sort an array by key in reverse order
krsort($sorted_sections);

foreach ( $sorted_sections as $section)
{ 
// Orig Code
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The proper way would be sorting the results when you call `parent->get_sections()`.  How you would do this is entirely up to the implementation of that class and method.  Changing this `foreach` to `for` for the sake of sorting seems like a code smell to me.

---

For the sake of answering the question as technical as possible.

```
$sections = $this->parent->get_sections(null, $this->parent->author);
$num_sections = count($sections);
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_sections; $i++) {
    // what you do here is up to you $sections[$i]
}
```

Comment: thanks, I know it seems like a code smell but unfortunately the plugin is sketchy and I need a a quick dirty fix.

Answer (score 2):

Especially if you are not aware of the specific number of sections, you could use `usort()` to do a dynamic custom sort on the `get_sections()`-returned array or object and then utilize the existing code. (This is a little more elegant, imo, than doing the same in a for/foreach loop).

Answer (score 1):

```
  $section = $this->parent->get_sections(null, $this->parent->author);
  echo $section[2]->name; 
  echo $section[1]->name;//just output the indexes the way you want
```

if you want it sorted, in say descending order, you can sort it that way and then use a `for` loop to display.